# How to split-screen camera on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-mobile

I want to split my back camera into two ui objects, like lenses. But there is an error when i launching the application. Here is it:

[image]

How to split camera into two objects? Here is my code: GamePage.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class GamePage : Page
{
    readonly Game1 _game;

    public GamePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Create the game.
       // var launchArguments = string.Empty;
        //_game = MonoGame.Framework.XamlGame<Game1>.Create(launchArguments, Window.Current.CoreWindow, swapChainPanel);
    }

    Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture captureManager;
    async private Task Start_Capture_Preview_Click()
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();    //Define MediaCapture object  
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();   //Initialize MediaCapture and   
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;   //Start preiving on CaptureElement  
        capturePreview2.Source = captureManager;   //Start preiving on CaptureElement  
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();  //Start camera capturing   
    }
    async private void Stop_Capture_Preview_Click()
    {
        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();  //stop camera capturing  

    }

    async private Task Start_Capture_Preview_ClickR()
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();    //Define MediaCapture object  
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();   //Initialize MediaCapture and   
        capturePreview2.Source = captureManager;   //Start preiving on CaptureElement  
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();  //Start camera capturing   
    }


    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await Start_Capture_Preview_Click();
        await Start_Capture_Preview_ClickR();
    }

}
```

GamePage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Victoria_XVR.GamePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Victoria_XVR"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="xD">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the MediaCapture supports streaming to multiple CaptureElements at the same time. It's a little painful to recommend this as a workaround, but in theory you could use the `GetPreviewFrameAsync` method in a timer, and render those frames to an Image control manually. There's [a sample](http://aka.ms/2015buildgetpreviewframesample) that shows how to use the API. I expect this will increase the memory and CPU usage, vs just rendering a single preview.